# Perspectives in 3D graphics with tikz: practical application

Tags: graphics, tikz-styles

### Objective

Below is a plot rendered in Mathematica. The goal is to reproduce this figure using tikz. After perusing many useful posts (such as [Tikz: drawing in perspective](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215464/tikz-drawing-in-perspective)), the solution is elusive.

[image: dual cells]

### Question

How can tikz be used to reproduce this figure?

### Best effort

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %
    \def\length{3.5}
    \def\dot{1.25}
    % origin
    \coordinate (org) at (0,0,0);
    % offsets
    \coordinate (yhat) at (0, 0, -\length);
    \coordinate (xhat) at (\length, 0, 0);
    \coordinate (zhat) at (0, \length, 0);
    % row 1
    \coordinate (a) at (org);
    \coordinate (b) at ( $(a) + (xhat)$ );
    \coordinate (c) at ( $(b) + (xhat)$ );
    % row 2
    \coordinate (d) at ( $(a) + (yhat)$ );
    \coordinate (e) at ( $(d) + (xhat)$ );
    \coordinate (f) at ( $(e) + (xhat)$ );
    % row 3
    \coordinate (g) at ( $(a) + (zhat)$ );
    \coordinate (h) at ( $(g) + (xhat)$ );
    \coordinate (i) at ( $(h) + (xhat)$ );
    % row 4
    \coordinate (j) at ( $(a) + (yhat) + (zhat)$ );
    \coordinate (k) at ( $(j) + (xhat)$ );
    \coordinate (l) at ( $(k) + (xhat)$ );
    %
    % lines
    %
    % long segments
    \draw[black]    (a) -- (c);
    \draw[black]    (g) -- (i);
    \draw[black]    (j) -- (l);
    % short segments
        % solids
    \draw[black]    (a) -- (g);
    \draw[black]    (b) -- (h);
    \draw[black]    (c) -- (i);
    \draw[black]    (g) -- (j);
    \draw[black]    (h) -- (k);
    \draw[black]    (i) -- (l);
    \draw[black]    (c) -- (f);
    \draw[black]    (f) -- (l);
        % dashed
    \draw[gray!50,dotted] (a) -- (d);
    \draw[gray!50,dotted] (d) -- (j);
    \draw[gray!50,dotted] (d) -- (f);
    \draw[gray!50,dotted] (b) -- (e);
    \draw[gray!50,dotted] (e) -- (k);
    %
    % labels
    %
    % bottom nodes
    \newcounter{k}
    \setcounter{k}{0}
    \foreach \n in {a, b, c}
        \stepcounter{k}
        \node at (\n)[below] {\number\value{k}};
    %
    % gray
    \setcounter{k}{3}
    \foreach \n in {d, e, f}
        \stepcounter{k}
        \node at (\n)[right,gray,fill=white] {\number\value{k}};
    %
    \setcounter{k}{6}
    \foreach \n in {g, h, i}
        \stepcounter{k}
        \node at (\n)[left,fill=white] {\number\value{k}};
    %
    \setcounter{k}{9}
    \foreach \n in {j, k, l}
        \stepcounter{k}
        \node at (\n)[above] {\number\value{k}};
    %
    % dots
    %
    % black nodes
    \foreach \n in {a, c, f, g, i, j, l}
        \node at (\n)[circle,fill,inner sep=\dot pt]{};
    %
    % red nodes
    \foreach \n in {b, h, k}
        \node at (\n)[circle,red,fill,inner sep=\dot pt]{};
    %
    % black nodes - hidden
    \foreach \n in {d, e}
        \node at (\n)[circle,black!50,fill,inner sep=\dot pt]{};
    %
    % red nodes - hidden
    \foreach \n in {e}
        \node at (\n)[circle,red!50,fill,inner sep=\dot pt]{};
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Critique

1. In the Mathematica image, every line is parallel to at least one other line. Not so in the tikz effort. For example 7-10 is not parallel to 9-12.
2. The default viewpoint in Mathematica produces a pleasing perspective which I have failed to reproduce in tikz.
3. The visual gravity of the first image surpases that of the second image.

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal example of what you tried so far.

Comment: At least the wording "solution is elusive" is amusing, and almost helps one to forget that this might be a "do-that-for-me" question. ;-) Yes, Ti*k*Z can definitely do that for you, and even better, [this stellar answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447120/121799) provides you with all the means to set up the corresponding three point perspective coordinate system.

Comment: I honestly do not understand your statement "In the Mathematica image, every line is parallel to at least one other line. Not so in the tikz effort. For example 7-10 is not parallel to 9-12." If you look at the very left and right planes in the mathematica output, you see that their shapes are different, i.e. their edges are *not* parallel. This is, of course, what the perspective view gives you. On the other hand, in the Ti*k*Z output `7-10` and `9-12` appear to be parallel. (And as for frustration saturation, well, I do not think any user of this site is responsible for this.)

Answer (score 7):

With [Max' stellar coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447120/121799) it is really straightforward.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\makeatletter

% Initialize H matrix for perspective view
\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@aa{1}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ab{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ac{0}%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ad{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ba{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@bb{1}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@bc{0}%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@bd{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ca{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@cb{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@cc{1}%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@cd{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@da{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@db{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@dc{0}%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@dd{1}

%Initialize H matrix for main rotation
\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@aa{1}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ab{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ac{0}%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ad{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ba{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@bb{1}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@bc{0}%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@bd{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ca{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@cb{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@cc{1}%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@cd{0}
%\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@da{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@db{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@dc{0}\pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@dd{1}

\pgfkeys{
    /three point perspective/.cd,
        p/.code args={(#1,#2,#3)}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(#1))}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\else
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ba{#2/#1}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ca{#3/#1}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@da{ 1/#1}
                \coordinate (vp-p) at (#1,#2,#3);
            \fi
        },
        q/.code args={(#1,#2,#3)}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(#2))}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\else
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ab{#1/#2}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@cb{#3/#2}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@db{ 1/#2}
                \coordinate (vp-q) at (#1,#2,#3);
            \fi
        },
        r/.code args={(#1,#2,#3)}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(#3))}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\else
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@ac{#1/#3}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@bc{#2/#3}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\H@tpp@dc{ 1/#3}
                \coordinate (vp-r) at (#1,#2,#3);
            \fi
        },
        coordinate/.code args={#1,#2,#3}{
            \def\tpp@x{#1}
            \def\tpp@y{#2}
            \def\tpp@z{#3}
        },
}

\tikzset{
    view/.code 2 args={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rot@main@theta{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rot@main@phi{#2}
        % Row 1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@aa{cos(\rot@main@phi)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ab{sin(\rot@main@phi)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ac{0}
        % Row 2
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@ba{-cos(\rot@main@theta)*sin(\rot@main@phi)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@bb{cos(\rot@main@phi)*cos(\rot@main@theta)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@rot@bc{sin(\rot@main@theta)}
        % Row 3
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@m@ca{sin(\rot@main@phi)*sin(\rot@main@theta)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@m@cb{-cos(\rot@main@phi)*sin(\rot@main@theta)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\H@m@cc{cos(\rot@main@theta)}
        % Set vector values
        \pgfmathsetmacro\vec@x@x{\H@rot@aa}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\vec@y@x{\H@rot@ab}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\vec@z@x{\H@rot@ac}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\vec@x@y{\H@rot@ba}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\vec@y@y{\H@rot@bb}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\vec@z@y{\H@rot@bc}
        % Set pgf vectors
        \pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{\vec@x@x cm}{\vec@x@y cm}}
        \pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{\vec@y@x cm}{\vec@y@y cm}}
        \pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{\vec@z@x cm}{\vec@z@y cm}}
    },
}

\tikzset{
    perspective/.code={\pgfkeys{/three point perspective/.cd,#1}},
    perspective/.default={p={(15,0,0)},q={(0,15,0)},r={(0,0,50)}},
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{three point perspective}{
    \pgfkeys{/three point perspective/.cd,coordinate={#1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp@p@w{\H@tpp@da*\tpp@x + \H@tpp@db*\tpp@y + \H@tpp@dc*\tpp@z + 1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp@p@x{(\H@tpp@aa*\tpp@x + \H@tpp@ab*\tpp@y + \H@tpp@ac*\tpp@z)/\temp@p@w}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp@p@y{(\H@tpp@ba*\tpp@x + \H@tpp@bb*\tpp@y + \H@tpp@bc*\tpp@z)/\temp@p@w}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp@p@z{(\H@tpp@ca*\tpp@x + \H@tpp@cb*\tpp@y + \H@tpp@cc*\tpp@z)/\temp@p@w}
    \pgfpointxyz{\temp@p@x}{\temp@p@y}{\temp@p@z}
}
\tikzaliascoordinatesystem{tpp}{three point perspective}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=4]
 \begin{scope}[
     view={60}{30},
     perspective={
         p={(-15,0,0)},q={(0,25,0)},r={(0,0,-30)}
     },bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},font=\sffamily]
  \foreach \X in {0,1,2}
  {\foreach \Y in {0,1}
  {\foreach \Z [evaluate=\Z as \L using {int(1+\X+3*\Y+6*\Z)}] in {0,1}
  {\ifnum\Z=0
   \path (tpp cs:\X,\Y,\Z) node[bullet,label=below:\L] (\L){};
  \else
   \path (tpp cs:\X,\Y,\Z) node[bullet,label=above:\L] (\L){};
  \fi}}}
  \draw[dotted] (1)  -- (4) -- (6)
  (4) -- (10)  (2) -- (5) -- (11);
  \draw (1) -- (3) -- (9) -- (7) -- (1)
  (9) -- (12) -- (10) -- (7)
  (3) -- (6) -- (12) (2) -- (8) -- (11);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you will have to adjust the view and/or perspective to your needs.

I really hope that this coordinate system will be part of a package some time soon.

**ADDENDUM**: You want parallel lines? Well, then you don't need any of these perspective thingies.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,>=latex,line join=bevel,font=\sffamily,
bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},scale=4]
  \foreach \X in {0,1,2}
  {\foreach \Y in {0,1}
  {\foreach \Z [evaluate=\Z as \L using {int(1+\X+3*\Y+6*\Z)}] in {0,1}
  {\ifnum\Z=0
   \path (\X,\Y,\Z) node[bullet,label=below:\L] (\L){};
  \else
   \path (\X,\Y,\Z) node[bullet,label=above:\L] (\L){};
  \fi}}}
  \draw[dotted] (1)  -- (4) -- (6)
  (4) -- (10)  (2) -- (5) -- (11);
  \draw (1) -- (3) -- (9) -- (7) -- (1)
  (9) -- (12) -- (10) -- (7)
  (3) -- (6) -- (12) (2) -- (8) -- (11);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this great effort. Can we create a figure such that each line belongs to one of two sets of parallel lines?

Comment: @dantopa Sure. Parallel lines are much easier.

Comment: Elegant approach to the problem. My earlier point should have been stated as "a little help from users like you often makes a big difference."

Answer (score 5):

You can set the 3D coordinate system in ordinary tikz. Without changes it becomes

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \foreach \pos [count=\Ind] in {{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{2,0,1},{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{2,0,0},{0,1,1},{1,1,1},{2,1,1},{0,1,0},{1,1,0},{2,1,0}}{
    \node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black,label=\ifnum\Ind<7 below\else above\fi:\Ind](p\Ind) at (\pos){};
  }
  \draw (p1)--(p2)--(p3)--(p6)--(p12)--(p11)--(p10)--(p7)edge(p1)--(p8)edge(p11)edge(p2)--(p9)edge(p12)--(p3);
  \draw[dotted] (p4)edge(p1)edge(p10)--(p5)edge(p2)edge(p11)--(p6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Then, changing x and z vectors you can redraw the same picture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={({cos(20)},{-sin(20)},0)},z={({-sin(40)},{-cos(40)},0)},scale=2]
  \foreach \pos [count=\Ind] in {{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{2,0,1},{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{2,0,0},{0,1,1},{1,1,1},{2,1,1},{0,1,0},{1,1,0},{2,1,0}}{
    \node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black,label=\ifnum\Ind<7 below\else above\fi:\Ind](p\Ind) at (\pos){};
  }
  \draw (p1)--(p2)--(p3)--(p6)--(p12)--(p11)--(p10)--(p7)edge(p1)--(p8)edge(p11)edge(p2)--(p9)edge(p12)--(p3);
  \draw[dotted] (p4)edge(p1)edge(p10)--(p5)edge(p2)edge(p11)--(p6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

This is not really a 3D drawing, just using three 2D vectors to draw the figure.

Comment: This is of course very minimal, and therefore attractive. Note, however, that these are not orthographic projections. In other words, a good reason for using tikz-3dplots and the like is that these are orthographic projections, i.e. an orthogonal rotation followed by a projection. That is, the results are then views (modulo perspective) that can be obtained from real things. If you just adjust `x`, `y` and `z` by hand, this cannot be guaranteed. Of course, this is not necessarily a bad thing, in fact some users as specifically for [such frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447991/121799).